# Can't figure out browserify-shim

Tags: browserify

Using Browserify, it appears I need this thing called "shim"?  All I want to do, is make a global variable "_" for lodash so that each reference to _ in the bundle is defined.

Surely someone else has done this for something like jQuery?

I've tried virtually every possible config permutation with browser-shim, browser-global-shim, and nothing seems to work.  Can someone please post their config that they used to make this type of thing work?

I just ended up doing this in my entry point file...
`window._ = require('lodash');`

That worked.  Whenever someone with some knowledge comes along, please help.

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me.

Comment: What is your package.json configuration for browserify-shim if you are using the latest version ?